# Unstable connection between two Yii Applications

Tags: php, yii, single-sign-on

I have two Yii Applications that are both using the same Database. I recently connected the two of them matching both Yii applications config file:

```
return array(
'id' => 'PROJECT',
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'project',

'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'class'=>'WebUser',

    ),
    'session'=> array(
        'timeout'=> 1440
    ),
    'partyroles'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'class'=>'WebUser',
    ),
```

Both applications have the same configuration as mentioned above. The purpose of connecting the two applications is to enable continuous activity between the two. For example, when a user logs into app1, he can access app2 without logging in and vice versa.

Problem is that it's unstable. Sometimes it doesn't work on other machines. Sometimes a user logs into app1 and cannot access app2 but when they access app2, they can access app1. What's the problem here?

**UPDATE**

Here is how I use CdbHttpSession to store sessions inside my database:

```
'session'=>array(
                    'class'=>'CDbHttpSession',
                    'connectionID'=>'db',
                    'sessionTableName'=>'YiiSession',
                    'timeout' => 1440
            ),
```

My table called YiiSession on the other hand stores the following data whenever a user logs in:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Just to clear things out, these two applications are under one domain and server.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like session issues. Are your two Yii apps on the same physical web server or are they different servers? How do you store session information? On the hard drive? In a database?

Comment: Both Yii apps are on the same webserver. www.mydomain.com/app1 and www.mydomain.com/app2   Session's are stored inside the database.

Comment: Is the instability always the same direction (app2 -> app1 works, but app1 -> app2 doesn't)?  Have you set the 'name' setting to be identical in both apps?  Unless it matches, your cookies will end up being different.  What else have you tried?

Comment: actually, the config file up there in my question is the same for both applications. The weird thing is that on my machine, there is no problem at all. On another machine app2->app1 works but app1->app2 works. On another machine, app1->app2 works, but app2->app1 does not work.

I set the 'id' as the same for both applications and even placed them at the highest level of my configuration files. I added the code above to show how I'm using the database stored session.

Comment: K, another question for you. You have mentioned three machines (your dev machine and then two others). Are the two others behind a load balancer (where the session is shared)? Do you have Suhosin installed by any chance? It caused me issues for a client with a load balancing setup ...

Comment: It's not actually just 3 machines. I even tested it on another machine that had nothing to do with development (all machines were macbook pros) and only my machine seems to have it work correctly. Also, when I first configured the settings, the feature was working fine for another machine and now for some reason, it is not.

Sometimes it works for the other machines on random hours.

and to answer your question about the load balancer, I'm not entirely sure if the systems have any but as far as I'm concerned, Suhosin or any load balancer is non-existent.

Comment: A new discovery:

On the other machines, the sessionID's are changing when they click on the link to the other application which resolves to not giving them access to the other application. But when they create a new tab and enter the link to the other app, the sessions remain the same.